# Adding UIPickerView Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am trying to add a `UIPickerView` programmatically but I am not getting the desired result.

I have a scroll view to which I have added a number of `UITextFields` as can be seen by the image below.

The idea is that when the user selects the `DATE`, a `UIDatePicker` is shown and the user selects the `DATE`. Pressing the `NEXT` button on the `DATE` pickers `UIBarButtonItem` (which I also added programatically), the `TIME` text field gets focus and the `UIDatePicker` (default to time) is shown. For the `DATE` and `TIME` fields I have used a `UIDatePicker` and this is working 100%.

[image]

For the remaining 3 text fields I am trying to do the same but using a `UIPickerView` instead, as they aren't of type `DATE` or `TIME`.

However, when I run my code, I get the following result as can be seen below. Possibly hard to make out from image but behind/over the bottom yellow `SEARCH` button is what should be the `UIPickerView` (can be seen as to grey lines just above the `PROFILE` and `SEARCH` bar items)

[image]

My `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods (`numberOfComponentsInPickerView`, `numberOfRowsInComponent`, `titleForRow` and `didSelectRow`) run when the view first appears but not again from what I can see when executing the program. In here I define what data array to display in either the Country or County text fields.

Below is the code I have to display the `UIPickerViews` programatically so far.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initPickers];
}

- (void) initPickers
{
    // Used for all other reusable UIPickerViews
    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
}
```

Then when e.g. the COUNTRY text field gets focus (this is tested and working), I animate the UIPickerView in as follows:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField*) textField
{
    activeTextField = textField;

    if (activeTextField.tag == 2)
    {
        self.countryTextField.inputView = pickerView;

        // We are on the Country Text Field
        currentArray = countryDataArray;
        NSLog(@"Array Count %ld", [currentArray count]);  // Is populated with data

        [self animatePickerViewIn];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void) animatePickerViewIn
{
    // Get the screen width and size
    float screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    float screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

    // Calculate the starting X Coordinate
    float pickerWidth = screenWidth;
    float pickerHeight = pickerView.frame.size.height;
    float pickerViewStartinYCoordinate = screenHeight - pickerView.frame.size.height;

    // Animate in and set PickerView to dimensions and coordinates
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [pickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, pickerViewStartinYCoordinate, pickerWidth, pickerHeight)];

        [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    }];
}
```

Can anyone please explain why I am not seeing the full UIPickerView?

Comment: Is that animation supposed to animate it in like the keyboard animates in? I think it will automatically do that for you just by setting it as the inputView like you did. Try taking away the animation and see if it works

Comment: Why do you need to try animating the picker view at all?

Comment: I tried removing the animation and just showing the picker when the view loads but still I get the same result as per the question. Heres how I tested it without animation: - (void) initPickers
{
    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    float screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    float screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    float pickerWidth = screenWidth;
    float pickerHeight = pickerView.frame.size.height;
    float pickerViewStartinYCoordinate = screenHeight - pickerView.frame.size.height;
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this is to set the date picker as the `inputView` of the text field. That way, when the text field becomes first responder, UIKit will take care of animating the date picker onto the screen (if appropriate). You can also set the toolbar with the Next button as the `inputAccessoryView` and UIKit will take care of displaying that too.

Here's what it looks like if you just set up date pickers and picker views as the input views of your text fields:

[image: demo]

Here's the source code for my demo app: https://github.com/mayoff/ios-picker-input-views